# dnn- add a mudule to a pane (on all pages) 3rd module from the top of the pane

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

i am able to add am module in the right pane of all my pages but when i add the original and position it in the middle of 5 already existing modules in the pane and set it to show on all pages it shows as the first module on every page except for the page i added it to originally where it is where i want it. i want it to be the 3rd module from the top inside the right pane.

am i missing a setting again?

Answer (score 0):

I generally cheat and do it through SQL as I haven't found another method that works consistently. If you know SQL, you just need update the ModuleOrder column in the TabModules table... I think it's best that I don't provide the actual SQL because I don't want people that don't really know SQL running it with incorrect values.